# How can I query list items using CAML

Tags: caml-query

I have 3 fields(Fname,Email,Phone)

```
<viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
 <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
  </viewFields> \
  <query> \
   <Query> \
<Where> \
<Contains> \
     <FieldRef Name='Title','Fname' /> \
         <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
  </Contains> \
  </Where> \
</Query> \
  </query> \
   </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Qassas</Value>
         </Contains>
         <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='Fname' />
            <Value Type='Text'>ww</Value>
         </Contains>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='Fname' />
   <FieldRef Name='Email' />
   <FieldRef Name='Phone' />
</ViewFields>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [u2u caml builder](https://www.u2u.be/software) to construct caml query.

Btw here is a sample code how you can create dynamic query.

```
SPList listPricing_Brandfamily = web.Lists["Pricing_Brandfamily"];
        SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
        oQuery.Query = "<Where>"
                    + "<And> "
                    + "<Eq> "
                    + " <FieldRef Name='BrandFamily_ID' /> "
                    + "  <Value Type='Lookup'>" + brandFamilyID.ToString() + "</Value> "
                    + " </Eq> "
                    + " <And> "
                    + " <Eq> "
                    + "    <FieldRef Name='CountryID' /> "
                    + "    <Value Type='Lookup'>" + countryID.ToString() + "</Value> "
                    + "  </Eq> "
                    + " <Eq> "
                    + "   <FieldRef Name='PackSize' /> "
                    + "   <Value Type='Number'>" + packSize.ToString() + "</Value> "
                    + " </Eq> "
                    + " </And> "
                    + " </And> "
        + " </Where>";
        SPListItemCollection collItem = listPricing_Brandfamily.GetItems(oQuery);
        if (collItem.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

You can also user `stringbuider` for better readability.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["RevisionChildWorkFlow"];
        SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("<Where>");
        query.Append("<And>");
        query.Append("<Eq>");
        query.Append("<FieldRef Name='RevisionID' />");
        query.Append("<Value Type='Lookup'>" + priceProposalID.ToString() + "</Value>");
        query.Append("</Eq>");
        query.Append("<And>");
        query.Append("<Eq>");
        query.Append("<FieldRef Name='UserGroup' />");
        query.Append("<Value Type='Text'>" + userGroupTypes.ToString() + "</Value>");
        query.Append("</Eq>");
        query.Append("<Eq>");
        query.Append("<FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE'/>");
        query.Append("<Value Type='Integer'>" + CurrentUserID + "</Value>");
        query.Append("</Eq>");
        query.Append("</And>");
        query.Append("</And>");
        query.Append("</Where>");
        oQuery.Query = query.ToString();

        SPListItemCollection collItem = list.GetItems(oQuery);
```